# How to access private method in another class?

Tags: java

Can you do a getter/setter for a private method in another class? If not, how would I access this method (without changing it from private to public unless that's the only way). For example, this is one class:

```
public class PlanBook {
      private boolean isPlanGoing (int plan){
      .....
      }
}
```

In another class where I have to use this method, I'm doing:

```
PlanBook pb = new PlanBook();
pb.isPlanGoing(1234);
```

But Intellij is telling me I can't do it cause its private "____ has private access in ______"

Comment: You could create a public method inside `PlanBook` that in turn calls `isPlanGoing`. Or just make it public...

Comment: Which classes should be able to access it? Why shouldn't this method be public? Can this method and the classes they are using it have the "package" visibility?

Comment: ```public boolean isPlanGoing (int plan)``` ?

Comment: All the other methods in the PlanBook class are private so I figure all of them are supposed to be private? I don't know if thats just good design (I don't want to mess it up) or they did that on purpose and theres just a way of calling the private method and I just don't know it

Comment: A class with only private methods makes actually not much, like 0, sense ...

Comment: Are there any annotations on the class? There could be autogenerated code like a builder or such. Other than that, instead of leaving the method untouched it's in almost all cases the better idea to adjust so the class fits its purpose IF you have control over the class. You might disagree with the original author what it's purpose is and then this is best discussed if you're part of a team maintaining the same code. If you don't have control over the class reflection would be an option, but that is somewhat hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method is private you cannot access it from another class.
Usually for private attributes that need to be access from other classes you use "get-ers" and "set-ers".

For example, adding this to the PlanBook class:

```
public boolean getIsPlanGoing(int plan) {

      return isPlanGoing(plan);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is likely to create a public method that calls your private method.

```java
public class PlanBook {
    private boolean isPlanGoing(int plan) {
      ...
    }
    public boolean isThisPlanGoing(int plan) {
      return isPlanGoing(plan);
    }
}
```

Comment: but only if there is a good reason to leave the private method untouched (and I cannot think of one right now, but heck, there might be weird legacy requirement due to some reflection going over the class looking for a private method or such). Without any good reason, this just adds confusion to the next person that looks at this class, is wondering why there are two identical methods and will likely remove one to clean up the class.